# Initialize custom uuid.UUID type in Golang

Tags: go, types, uuid

In Golang it is valid to create a type:

```
type RoleID uuid.UUID

n1 := RoleID(uuid.New())

fmt.Println("n: ", n1)
```

does not seem to work. I want

```
n: 35ae88a1-72cd-4116-9d32-b9762ecb51b4
```

**output**

```
n:  [12 86 96 165 221 15 69 229 148 188 84 87 1 177 30 67]
```

Comment: What you've got is a byte representation of the result. Convert it to string to see the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.String()` for the format you want:

```
type RoleID = uuid.UUID

n1 := RoleID(uuid.New())

fmt.Println("n: ", n1.String())
```